# Using distinct on other field of selected ids postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this data

```
Table
id  weight
1   1000
1   1000
2   2000
2   2000
3   3000
4   3000
```

I am trying to find average of weight of distinct ids except 4 and I need data in this format

```
 id          avg(weight) 
 1,2,3          2000
```

I have tried distinct but it gives me average including all duplicate values.

```
SELECT
    String_agg(distinct id :: text, ', ') AS ids,
    Round(Coalesce(Avg(weight), 0)) AS avg
FROM "table"
where id != 4
```

I have also tried group by id but it gives me data in different format and also it is not giving me correct average.

```
SELECT
    String_agg(id :: text, ', ') AS ids,
    Round(Coalesce(Avg(weight), 0)) AS avg
FROM "table"
where id != 4
group by id
```

so how can I find average for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try using your current logic on a subquery which finds the distinct records:

```
SELECT
    STRING_AGG(id::text, ',' ORDER BY id) AS ids,
    ROUND(COALESCE(AVG(weight), 0)) AS avg
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id, weight
    FROM "table"
    WHERE id <> 4
) t;
```

### Demo

Note: I added an `ORDER BY` clause to your `STRING_AGG` call, to ensure that the ids appear in the order you want.